# ASP.NET access non-server controls inside Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, panel

I've got a custom control that inherits from `Panel`.  At Load-time, I want to access all of the controls inside of this panel, including non-server controls, to manipulate the attributes. The `Controls` property of the panel gives me the server controls, but not the non-server ones.  Is there any way to access them?

For example:

```
<cc:MyPanel runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" />
    <input type="text" id="txt2" />
</cc:MyPanel>
```

During the `Load` event (or really any event before the control is rendered), I want to manipulate both text boxes.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to either add `runat='server'` on each tag or do some JavaScript to handle this.
The load event is looking at server controls.

Change your control to:

```
<input id="txt2" runat="server" type="text" />
```

Then you can do:

```
string s = txt2.Text;
```

The only other way I can think of is if you wanted to actually use a form to post the values and then use `Request.` to access each variable that you are posting.  But my thought is you are looking more for the former rather then the latter.

Finally if you go the JS route here is a nice article from MSDN showing you how to do this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a.aspx

Comment: If using Javascript, take a look at `Page.ClientScript` to register javascript code/includes at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I specifically didn't want to force these to be server controls, since I wanted to just wrap it around existing markup, but I hadn't thought about using javascript.  That should work for me.

Comment: This got me really curious, @JoeEnos, because I was wondering why you were using an aspnet textbox and an input/text in the same control, when the aspnet textbox itself renders as an input/text control, so why not use two aspnet textboxes? There must be some special reason why your approach was necessary and I'd be curious to know what it was!

Comment: Nothing special. I'm building a control that just wraps around existing markup, making things visible, invisible, or readonly based on user permissions. Various forms are done differently throughout our solution, so I just wanted to make sure that this control functions for either ASP.NET server controls, or for client controls. They probably wouldn't exist together, but I wanted my control to function regardless of which way the page was designed.

Comment: Hey, I wouldn't have thought of that.  Cool!  Thanks!

Comment: The disappointing part is that no matter how I do it, I can't use this for true security - I'll still need to validate on the server that users can't modify form elements that they're not allowed to, since users can of course manipulate forms through javascript consoles, or simply manually post whatever they feel like. But it works as a pretty good first step.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the RegisterStartupScript method.  I did a quick test project and while I don't know the specifics of your project, a combination of client side and server side controls inside of a panel are accessed and modified successfully in my test.

```
<asp:Panel ID="customPanel1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <input type="text" id="clientSideInput1" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="clientSideInput2" /><br />
</asp:Panel> 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var controls = customPanel1.Controls;
    foreach(Control c in controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            ((TextBox)c).Text = "It worked!";
    }
    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(GetType(), "PageScripts"))
    {
        var jscript = "document.getElementById('clientSideInput1').style.background=\"Red\";";
        jscript += "document.getElementById('clientSideInput2').style.background=\"Yellow\";";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "PageScripts", jscript, true);
    }
}
```

Produces this for me...

[image]

Hope that gets you going!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually needing to handle this for an arbitrary number of elements, so I won't have the specific IDs in the server code. My solution was to use javascript (jQuery specifically) to access each element inside of my panel, and do what needed to be done.